# Kullback-Liebler's divergence on a conditioned function

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, kullback-leibler, metric, conditioning

Let $q$ be a conditioned pdf over $\mathbf{X}=X_1,\dots,X_n$ binary r.v.s in the form $$q(\mathbf{X})=\begin{cases}q_{0}(\mathbf{X}_{\setminus i}) \text{ if } X_{i}=0\\q_{1}(\mathbf{X}_{\setminus i}) \text{ if } X_{i}=1\end{cases}$$

where $X_{i}\in \mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{X}_{\setminus i} = \mathbf{X} \setminus \{X_{i}\}$.

To estimate the Kullback-Leibler divergence of $q$ against a another distribution $p$ on some observations $O=\{o_1,\dots,o_m\}$ over $\mathbf{X}$, i.e. $D_{O}(p||q)$, is it legit to write something like this:
$$D_{O}(p||q) = D_{O_{i}^{0}}(p||q_{0})+D_{O_{i}^{1}}(p||q_{1})$$
where $O_{i}^{0}=\{o_j|o_j\in O, o_j(i) = 0\}$, that is, it is the subset of $O$ for which the value in correspondence of $X_i$ is 0 (same for the case with 1)?

In practice, since I am determining my function to be defined on different "intervals", when to estimate the divergence, I am summing the divergences between the function $p$ and the two pieces on the two observation partitions. If it were a distance and not a divergence I would be more confident about the meaning of this writing, is this still correct?